# How to avoid printing utf-8 characters in BeautifulSoup with replace_with

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, beautifulsoup

I am having a problem and I can find a way to solve it. I am trying to parse an html page and then replace a string, while using [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). Although the process looks correct and I do not get any errors when I open the new html page I get some utf-8 characters inside that I do not want.

Sample of working code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import codecs
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_sample = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head lang="en"><meta charset="UTF-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"></head>
<body>
<div class="date">LAST UPDATE</div>
</body>
</html>
"""

try:
    my_soup = BeautifulSoup(html_sample.decode('utf-8'), 'html.parser')  # html5lib or html.parser
    forecast = my_soup.find("div", {"class": "date"})
    forecast.tag = unicode(forecast).replace('LAST UPDATE', 'TEST')
    forecast.replace_with(forecast.tag)
    # print(my_soup.prettify())

    f = codecs.open('test.html', "w", encoding='utf-8')
    f.write(my_soup.prettify().encode('utf-8'))
    f.close()
except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
    print('Error, encoding/decoding: {}'.format(e))
except IOError as e:
    print('Error Replacing: {}'.format(e))
except RuntimeError as e:
    print('Error Replacing: {}'.format(e))
```

And the output with utf-8 characters in the new html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head lang="en">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
  </meta>
 </head>
 <body>
  &lt;div class="date"&gt;TEST&lt;/div&gt;
 </body>
</html>
```

I think that I have mixed up, the encoding and decoding process. Someone with more knowledge on this area can possible elaborate more. I am a total beginner on coding and encoding.

Thank you for your time and effort in advance.

Comment: you're replacing `forecast.tag` with the processed string replacement of the whole `forecast` element. that hasn't really anything to do with encoding.

Comment: If I do not do it like this, who it should be done? This is the only way that I found that it was working. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to get into encoding here. You can replace the text content of a Beautiful Soup element by setting the `element.string` as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_sample = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head lang="en"><meta charset="UTF-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"></head>
<body>
<div class="date">LAST UPDATE</div>
</body>
</html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_sample)
forecast = soup.find("div", {"class": "date"})
forecast.string = 'TEST'
print(soup.prettify())
```

**Output**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head lang="en">
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="date">
   TEST
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: OMG was that simple, and I could not figure it out. Thanks a lot for the answer. My alternative solution was to create a copy and formatted by string replacing process. But this is a much better solution. Thank again.

Comment: No worries - if it's any consolation I also find character encoding very confusing!

Comment: Two days now I am reading so much documentations and I could not figure it out. You saved my weekend... :D

Comment: @Thanos: If you find Unicode confusing you may find this article helpful: [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Comment: Thanks, it seems really interesting. I will definitely spend some time on it.